# My graph on matplotlib isn't plotting from when i want

Tags: python

```
!pip install yfinance
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
%matplotlib inline
start = "2017-01-01"
end = "2022-1-01"

FTSE100 = yf.download('^FTSE')
```

[Why is this plotting from so early when I have included the parameters??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynosw.png)

```
FTSE100['Open'].plot(label = 'FTSE100', figsize = (15,7))
```

Comment: `start` and `end` are defined, but not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the libary, so I could not test it. But according to the [docs](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance), it should work like this:

```
FTSE100 = yf.download('^FTSE', start=start, end=end)
```

After defining the parameters, you need to provide them to `yf.download` to use them.

Comment: will give this a go now thanks, really strange because when i ran this yesterday with different stocks it worked fine :/

Comment: @Drew2005 either the code was different, or it's just a coincidence with when data were available for those stocks

Comment: All works out cheers!

Comment: @Drew2005 glad to hear, feel free to mark accept the answer.